# List / output comma-separated values from single input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about outputting a list (whether as individual values or as an array) from a comma-separated value in a single input field?

**Example**

User enters the following into a text input field: *Steve, Bruce, Matt, Natasha, Peter*

Result:

- *Steve*
- *Bruce*
- *Matt*
- *Natasha*
- *Peter*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131678/convert-comma-separated-list-to-unordered-list

Answer (score 1):

Just split the input on comma, and generate the list

```js
var input = "Steve, Bruce, Matt, Natasha, Peter",
    ul    = $('<ul />');

input.split(',').forEach(function(item) {
    ul.append(
        $('<li />', { text : item })
    )
});

$('body').append(ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps you:

```
var myArray = $('input').val().split(',');
```

Using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Since you put `jquery` in your tags i guess you want a jQuery solution.

First of all you would want to split the values, and after that create a list (`ul` or `ol`) and add list elements (`li`)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#valuesForm").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    var values = $("#textfieldId").val().split(",");
    if (values) {
      for (var i in values) {
        var value = values[i].trim(),
          $valueList = $("#valueList"),
          $valueItem = $("<li />");
        $valueItem.text(value);
        $valueList.append($valueItem);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="valuesForm">
  <input type="text" id="textfieldId">
  <input type="submit" value="Split!">
</form>
<ul id="valueList">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

**1** Splitting

```
var aux = "Steve, Bruce, Matt, Natasha, Peter";
aux = aux.split(',');
```

This one gives you the names within an array but with the space after the comma.

**2** White Space Removal

```
var aux = "Steve, Bruce, Matt, Natasha, Peter";
aux = aux.split(', ');
```

This one does resolve the white-space after the comma.

**3** Alternative

```
var aux = "Steve, Bruce, Matt, Natasha, Peter";
aux = aux.split(',');

aux = jQuery.map( aux, function( n, i ) {
  return n.trim();
});
```

This last one is more flexible and i'm showing it just to give an example.